# How to locate where to hard code attribute within template source?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, vs-web-site-project

I'm new to web development and started working with a WP theme. So far I've got most of the customization done. Need help finding out how to edit this one attribute that's not an easily customizable component from within the CM system.

http://themes.themegoods.com/grandnews/demo1/

The attribute is the first "Advertisement" text that you see here when inspecting.

[Location within code source needed to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU7hf.jpg)

How do I find out where to manually edit this "ads_label"?

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is a widget, try going to `Appearances > widgets` and find the widget and modify it there - here is an example where you can find widgets:

[image]

Comment: Yes I can edit the picture but not the text that says "Advertisement" right above it. Everything that's editable in the Appearance or Widgets I can edit but not the text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was hidden within the Themes folder which required a sudo chmod to change the php file and then reupload the changed source echo code line.

Thanks for the help!